# Invalid object name 'table1.CreatedAt'. Error coming in SQL server even though the table exists

Tags: mysql, sql, object, syntax

```
SELECT table1.CreatedAt

FROM table1 

LEFT JOIN table1.CreatedAt 

ON table1.CreatedAt=[testDebtMarketData$].Date

WHERE [testDebtMarketData$].Date = NULL
```

but when I do `SELECT * FROM table1` it works and I can see the table...

Comment: You need to specify a _table_ directly after `LEFT JOIN`, not a column.

Comment: for checking the `NULL` value you have to use `IS` Keyword: `[testDebtMarketData$].Date IS NULL`

Comment: = works as well

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to specify a **table** directly after *LEFT JOIN,* not a column.